# WPF RichTextBox Control, How To Find All Italicized Words

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

How can you loop through all the "words" (spaces deliminate words) in an RTB (WPF Control) to see which ones are italicized?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextPointer tp = RTB.Document.ContentStart;
TextRange word = WordBreaker.GetWordRange(tp);

   while (word.End.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward) != null)
        {
            if (word.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontStyleProperty).ToString() == "Italic")
            {

            }
            word = WordBreaker.GetWordRange(word.End.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward));  
        }
    }
```

with WordBreaker class from
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/prajakta/navigate-words-in-richtextbox)

Answer (score 0):

Well, your task seems to be a quite complicated one.

The contents of a `RichTextBox` is a [`FlowDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.aspx) which can be found at the property [`Document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document.aspx). The `FlowDocument`, in turn, consists of several [`Blocks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.blocks.aspx).

Each of the [`Block`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.block.aspx)s can be a [`Paragraph`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.paragraph.aspx), a [`Section`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.section.aspx), a [`Table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.table.aspx) etc. You'll need to analyze each of them separately.

For the `Paragraph`, it consists of several [`Inlines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.paragraph.inlines.aspx), each of them can be a [`Span`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.span.aspx#inheritanceContinued), which in turn may be an [`Italic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.italic.aspx). The `Italic` represents italicized text. The `Italic` can, in turn, have other inlines, containing other `Span`s  (for example, `Hyperlink`s, which you may or may not want to include into your result).

You you basically need to traverse all the structure recursively and peek the text from your `Italic`s. A special case may be the words where only a part is italicized, you'll need to have a strategy for them.

I am unaware of any easier methods to achieve what you want. HTH.

Edit:
Perhaps an easier alternate solution would be to traverse all the text using [`TextPointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textpointer.aspx) from the beginning (`richTextBox.Document.ContentStart`), switching to the next position with `position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward)`, and testing if your current position is inside an `Italic` using `position.Parent`. You should however care that `Italic` can be a non-immediate parent, so you'll perhaps need to traverse several parents upwards. Disclaimer: I did never try this idea in my code.

Comment: I used your basic idea of checking each for to see if it is italic or not

Comment: TextPointer tp = RTB.Document.ContentStart;
            TextRange word = WordBreaker.GetWordRange(tp);

            while (word.End.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward) != null)
            {
                if (word.GetPropertyValue(TextElement.FontStyleProperty).ToString() == "Italic")
                {

                }
                word = WordBreaker.GetWordRange(word.End.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward));  
            }
        }

Comment: with WordBreaker class from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prajakta/archive/2006/11/01/navigate-words-in-richtextbox.aspx